# SQL Aggregate most frequent value with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
PARTNUMBER | QUANTITY | DESCRIPTION
'foo'        2          'a'
'foo'        2          'a1'
'bar'        2          'b'
'bar'        2          'b'
'bar'        2          'b1'
'bizz'       2          'c'
```

I'm trying to group by PARTNUMBER, aggregate by QUANTITY, and aggregate DESCRIPTION by most-frequent appearance.

I tried using a sub-query to aggregate DESCRIPTION by its most frequent occurrence, but I'm having some trouble getting it right, especially with GROUP BY.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, PARTNNUMBER, 
    (SELECT TOP(1) [DESCRIPTION]
    FROM [PBJobDB].[dbo].[DEVICES]
    /*WHERE DESCRIPTION = t1.PARTNO ?? */
    GROUP BY [DESCRIPTION], PARTNNUMBER
    ORDER BY COUNT([DESCRIPTION]) DESC) as [DESCRIPTION]
FROM `database.table`
GROUP BY PARTNUMBER, [DESCRIPTION]
```

The subquery is not getting the most frequent DESCRIPTION by PARTNUMBER, and instead gives the most frequent DESCRIPTION in the whole table.

I would like the output to look like this:

```
PARTNUMBER | QUANTITY | DESCRIPTION
'foo'        4          'a'
'bar'        6          'b'
'bizz'       2          'c'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried below one, please check whether its working for you,

```
SELECT PARTNUMBER,SUM(QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY,  
(
    SELECT TOP 1 DESCP FROM
        (SELECT [DESCRIPTION]'DESCP',COUNT(*)'CNT'
        FROM testtable
        WHERE PARTNUMBER = t1.PARTNUMBER
        GROUP BY [DESCRIPTION]) A 
    GROUP BY DESCP,CNT HAVING CNT=MAX(CNT) 
)as [DESCRIPTION]
FROM testtable  T1
GROUP BY PARTNUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me...

```
select distinct t1.PARTNUMBER , sum(t1.QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY, (
    select TOP(1) [DESCRIPTION]
    from [PBJobDB].[dbo].[DEVICES] AS t2
    where t2.PARTNUMBER = t1.PARTNUMBER 
    group by [DESCRIPTION]
    order by count(*) desc ) as [DESCRIPTION] 
from `database.table` AS t1 
/* WHERE `column` IS NULL AND `other_column` = 'some_value' */ 
GROUP BY t1.PARTNUMBER
```

Comment: Distinct serves no purpose here. You group by partnumber so you get one row per partnumber. Adding distinct does reduce the number of rows in the resultset. The back ticks suggest you are not using sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the *mode*.  I would use two levels of aggregation:

```
select partnumber, sum(quantity) as total_quantity,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then description end) as description
from (select partnumber, description, sum(quantity) as quantity,
             row_number() over (partition by partnumber order by sum(quantity) desc, description) as seqnum
      from t
      group by partnumber, description
     ) pd
group by partnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Sum() over to get total quantity. Below is the example that worked for me.

```
SELECT      PARTNUMBER, QUANTITY, DESCRIPTION
    FROM        (
        SELECT      PARTNUMBER,SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY PARTNUMBER ORDER BY CAST(PARTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(30)) ) Quantity,DESCRIPTION,R
        FROM        (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARTNUMBER ORDER BY COUNT(DESCRIPTION) DESC) R, 
                        SUM(Quantity) Quantity, --OVER (PARTITION BY PARTNUMBER ORDER BY CAST(PARTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(30)) ) Quantity,
                        PARTNUMBER,
                        DESCRIPTION
                FROM    #Temp 
                GROUP BY PARTNUMBER,DESCRIPTION 
        ) AS S
    ) AS S
WHERE R = 1
```